# sonar-scanner.bat fails with 401 on api/settings/values.protobuf when executed by jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

When I execute the pipeline below I get a 401 error on http://mysonarhost.my.domain:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf.

The same command executes without errors from a command prompt.
The api/settings/values.protobuf URL can be accessed using a browser.

I tried setting the token in various places but none seem to help .

## Versions

- sonarqube Version 6.3.1 (build 21392)
- Jenkins ver. 2.75 on RHEL 7
- Jenkins Node on windows 2012 R2
- sonar-scanner 2.8

## pipeline

[image: screenshot of pipeline script]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bYiD.png

## log

```
sonar-scanner -X -Dproject.settings=..\sonar_ccesmarttools.properties -Dsonar.logon=mytoken 
06:32:33.829 INFO: Scanner configuration file: X:\workspaces\common\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonarQubeScanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
06:32:33.836 INFO: Project root configuration file: X:\cce\SmartLisaNightly\git\ccesmarttools\CceSmartTools\..\sonar_ccesmarttools.properties
06:32:33.873 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
06:32:33.874 INFO: Java 1.8.0_73 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
06:32:33.874 INFO: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
06:32:33.874 INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx16g
06:32:34.041 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
06:32:34.042 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
06:32:34.042 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
06:32:34.042 DEBUG: init keystore
06:32:34.042 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
06:32:34.158 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\jenkinsuser\.sonar\cache
06:32:34.158 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
06:32:34.173 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
06:32:34.173 DEBUG: Download: http://mysonarhost.my.domain:9000/batch/index
06:32:34.232 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
06:32:34.233 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
06:32:34.243 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
06:32:34.255 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
06:32:34.255 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
06:32:34.260 DEBUG: Execution start
06:32:34.557 DEBUG: Publish global mode
06:32:34.698 INFO: Load global settings
06:32:34.749 DEBUG: GET 401 http://mysonarhost.my.domain:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=43ms
06:32:34.751 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:32:34.751 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
06:32:34.751 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:32:34.751 INFO: Total time: 0.961s
06:32:34.788 INFO: Final Memory: 17M/1963M
06:32:34.788 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:32:34.788 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token), the property should be `sonar.login`, not `sonar.logon`.

Comment: And as a side note, your token shouldn't be in clear text in your pipeline description. You should use the `withCredentials` node (see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/ ) and store the token in Jenkins.

Comment: This solved my problem, for some reason unknown to me it did not matter that I had the wrong property when I ran for a command line

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it thanks to Gilles QUERRET answer and comments.

- the token should be in the **sonar.login** property
- added the **withCredentials** node
- stored the token with id SONAR_TOKEN in http://myjenkinsserver:8090/credentials/store/system/domain/_/
- changed single quotes in the bat command to double quotes to allow $SONAR_TOKEN to be evaluated
- not part of the initial question, added `-Dsonar.projectVersion=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` to show the Jenkins build number in SonarQube

### Working stage definition

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
  withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
      withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'SONAR_TOKEN', variable: 'SONAR_TOKEN')]) {
          def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner';
          env.PATH = "${scannerHome}\\bin;${env.PATH}";
          dir('X:\\cce\\SmartLisaNightly\\git\\smartlisa\\SmartLisaFrontend') {
              bat "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dproject.settings=..\\sonar_SmartLisaFrontend.properties -Dsonar.projectVersion=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
          }
      }
  }
}
```